# Is it possible to use wildcard logic '*' to list a specific directory via Apache Maven Goals & Options?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, cucumber

I need to list a specific directory using wildcard logic within my Maven goals and options command.

Currently the root directory is: 
`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="C:/Users/Joe_Blogs/Desktop/AutoFramework/src/test/resources/features/Bookings/MakeBooking.feature"`

I need to use ** to scan the project folders in order to search for a given feature file, as the folder name (Bookings) may change.
`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="C:/Users/Joe_Blogs/Desktop/AutoFramework/src/test/resources/features/**/MakeBooking.feature"`

In the example above ** will need to reference a variety of different folders, not just Bookings.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven supports the "any" and "any descendant" wildcard denoted by `*` and `**`, respectively. It is a subset of the [`<fileset>` Ant convention](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).

The support comes from the [Apache Maven Shared Utils](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-utils/) library. The actual logic of walking directory trees, path normalization, pattern matching, etc. is grouped inside the [org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-utils/xref/org/apache/maven/shared/utils/io/package-summary.html) package. Those classes provides uniform file system handling across [plugins supported by the the Maven Project](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/).

As the references should demonstrate, wildcard processing is neither trivial logic, nor magically applied outside of Maven proper. Cucumber has to intentionally support the syntax somehow. Sorry, but it doesn't look like Cucumber supports the "any descendant" wildcard. The closest equivalent is `/*` at the end of a path.

However, one possible workaround is to use [tags](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags). Maybe it will seem silly to tag a single file, but doing so dispenses any concern about pathing. Example:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @MakeBooking"
```